# Disabling resharper errors through vs config

Tags: resharper, resharper-5.0

We are using resharper in our project, but based on our pattern and pratices we follow different naming conventions for classes,variables and so on. But we still need to use resharper, is there any configuration entry that we can make to disable these warnings.
I know about disabling them by configuring in VS but that will only help for client machine and on server where we will be building our code we again will get those warnings.
Help!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You have Resharper on the build server and it is some how interfering with the build?

Comment: No, Its just that when the code builds on the build sever its logs all the FxCop warnings and resharper warnings. FxCop we have taken care of its just the Resharper which keeps on giving the warnings because we follow different naming conventions for our projects. Is there any config entry that i can make to disable just the naming convention warning

Comment: Why do have Resharper on the build server? I makes no sense.

Comment: You should consider upgrading to ReSharper 7.0, it has more flexible options for naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable those options. For each quick-fix notification, you can modify `ReSharper->Options->Code Inspection->Inspection Severity` to set whether it's a "Do not show", "Hint", "Suggestion", "Warning" or "Error". Although, if it's causing you pain, just don't capture ReSharper errors on your build server.